# Add fragment on navigation controller instead of replace fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationcontroller

I am using Navigation control (Android Architecture). I used some demo and creating navigation architecture. But the problem is, fragment is getting recalled every time just like: replace fragment when you back from any fragment. So how can I stop this, and how can I set behaviour like Add fragment instead of replace fragment.

I found this problem on web but no one is giving me idea that how to add/replace fragment on navigation control. I tried fragment id to get add fragment approach but not get success.

1. This is my navigation host xml : I am adding one fragment again and again 
   with logging life cycle.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/questionanswer">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/questionanswer"
                android:name="com.softtech360.totalservey.fragment.QuestionAnswer"
                android:label="fragment_first"
                tools:layout="@layout/questionanswer" >
                <action
                    android:id="@+id/action_questionanswer_to_questionanswer"
                    app:destination="@id/questionanswer"

                    />
            </fragment>
</navigation>
```

2. I created one button, using this I call every time trigger the function and swap the fragment on host fragment :

```java
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!,R.id.navhost_fragment)
                            navController.navigate(R.id.questionanswer)
        // using this i swap the fragment on host fragment.
```

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? If you're actually [saving your state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state), then you're fragment will be in exactly the same state as it was in whether you use add or replace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_questionanswer_to_questionanswer"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/questionanswer"/>
```

instead of

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_questionanswer_to_questionanswer"
    app:destination="@id/questionanswer"/>
```

and then:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_questionanswer_to_questionanswer)
```

Found this [here](https://programmerr47.medium.com/navigate-back-with-navigation-component-6cec37ba6964)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without changing destination to popUpTop.

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_questionanswer_to_questionanswer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this line

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!,R.id.navhost_fragment)
                        navController.navigate(R.id.questionanswer)
```

and run your app again.